# Bash - Sort File Based on 2 Columns : HH:MM:SS AM/PM

Tags: bash, sorting, timestamp

Trying to sort lines in a file. The column1 is HH:MM:SS format and col2 is AM/PM. Need to arrange lines from AM to PM firstly and then progressive time.

Current :

```
11:36:48 AM col3 ...
11:32:00 AM col3 ...
03:18:54 PM col3 ...
02:26:40 PM col3 ...
01:51:56 PM col3 ...
12:55:58 PM col3 ...
11:58:48 AM col3 ...
09:38:41 AM col3 ...
```

Final:

```
09:38:41 AM col3 ...
11:32:00 AM col3 ...
11:36:48 AM col3 ...
11:58:48 AM col3 ...
12:55:58 PM col3 ...
01:51:56 PM col3 ...
02:26:40 PM col3 ...
03:18:54 PM col3 ...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate a 24H equivalent of your AM/PM times and prepend it to the line with `awk`. Then `sort` will work fine and all that's left to do is to strip the added data (with `sed` or `cut` or whatever):

```bash
awk -F '[ :]' '
    {
        H24 = ($1 == 12 ? ($4 == "AM" ? 0 : 12) : ($4 == "PM" ? $1 + 12 : $1))
        print sprintf("%02d%02d%02d", H24, $2, $3), $0
    }
' data.txt |
sort |
sed 's/[^ ]* //'
```

Answer (score 3):

A Schwartzian transform:

```bash
while read -ra fields; do
    printf '%s\t%s\n' "$(date -d "${fields[*]:0:2}" '+%s')" "${fields[*]}"
done < input \
| sort -n \
| cut -f 2-
```

outputs

```
09:38:41 AM col3 ...
11:32:00 AM col3 ...
11:36:48 AM col3 ...
11:58:48 AM col3 ...
12:55:58 PM col3 ...
01:51:56 PM col3 ...
02:26:40 PM col3 ...
03:18:54 PM col3 ...
```

The while loop calculates the epoch time for each timestamp and adds it to the output stream. Then it gets sorted by the numeric time. Then that field is removed.

Doing this in bash may be slower than doing it in, say, perl:

```bash
perl -MTime::Piece -lane '
        push @lines, [@F];
    } END {
        print join "\n",
              map {"@{$_->[1]}"}
              sort {$a->[0] <=> $b->[0]}
              map {[Time::Piece->strptime("$_->[0] $_->[1]", "%T %p")->epoch, $_]}
              @lines;
' input
```

Comment: Thanks! It gave the correct output format, but since we also needed to remove duplicate records using -u in sort, it didnt produce the current number of unique records. Also as you mentioned this takes too much time because of epoch calc. (Didnt try the perl menthod).

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is get the AM lines with `grep`, then use `sort` on the output. After doing that then you can do the same for the PM lines.

```
cp "my_file" "backup_file" #Backup old file before overwriting
grep '^[0-9:]* AM' "backup_file" | sort > "my_file"
grep '^[0-9:]* PM' "backup_file" | sort >> "my_file"
```

Its important to backup your file before using `>` operation since that will completely overwrite your file.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment, sorting on the current time column will be problematic in that the `12:xx` entries need to come before `01:xx` entries.

One approach:

- convert the `12:xx` entries to `00:xx`
- run a normal 2-column sort
- convert the `00:xx` entries back to `12:xx`

One `sed | sort | sed` idea:

```
$ sed 's/^12/00/' sample.log | sort -k2,2 -k1,1 | sed 's/^00/12/'
09:38:41 AM col3 ...
11:32:00 AM col3 ...
11:36:48 AM col3 ...
11:58:48 AM col3 ...
12:55:58 PM col3 ...
01:51:56 PM col3 ...
02:26:40 PM col3 ...
03:18:54 PM col3 ...
```